# Accidentally made backdrop viewer size zero. How to get it back?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I accidentally decreased the size of the viewer in the backdrop to zero. Now it displays as a small cross and I cannot reach the handles to enlarge it again. Does anyone know how to get it back, without needing to rebuild my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the sidebar in the compositor <kbd>N</kbd>
2. Open the *View* tab
3. Increase the *Zoom* property in the *Backdrop* panel. Alternatively you can use *Fit* to fit the background image into the view or *Reset Backdrop* to reset the offset and zoom.

[image: Screenshot]